# How to get an object in Firestore (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

How do you get an object in Firestore by its id in Swift? I would then need to use this object to generate content in the UI. I am using SwiftUI.
The object I am trying to get is a user and it has the following structure:

```
struct AppUser: Codable {

    var id: String
    var displayName: String
    var photoURL: String
    var points: Int
    var knownLanguageCodes: Set<String>

}
```

The each document in the "users" collection has the fields in the AppUser struct. Ideally, I would like to write a function that returns an AppUser object from Firestore:

```
func getUser(withId id: String) -> AppUser {
    //I don't know how to write this function
}
```

The object would then be used like this:

```
struct ProfileHeadingView: View {

    let userId: String
    let user = getUser(withId: userId)

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ImageView(withURL: self.user.photoURL)
                .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text(self.user.displayName)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                HStack {
                    Text(String(self.user.points))
                        .font(.title)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of Firebase's APIs are asynchronous - this is due to the fact that most of them involve a network call, which is much slower than code gets executed on your phone!

So, your `getUser` method would need to be rewritten like this:

```swift
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

func getUser(userId: String, completion: @escaping (_ user: AppUser?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
  db.collection("users").document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
    let user = try? snapshot?.data(as: AppUser.self)
    completion(user, error)
  }
}
```

Note: to be able to use Firestore's Codable support, you will have to add `pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'` to your `Podfile`

As for how (and when) to fetch the user, this largely depends on whether `ProfileHeadingView` is part of a list view (or is being navigated to from a list view), or not.

If it is part of a list view, I'd recommend fetching all users at once - you can either use a snapshot listener to [listen for any updates to the users collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), or perform a [one-time fetch to read the users collection once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Then, from the list view, pass the respective `user` object into the `ProfileHeadingView`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting the error "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'as:', expected 'with:')" on line 3 of the function.

Comment: You need to add `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` to your Pods and then import `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` in your Swift file. This will allow you to easily read/write structs that implement `Codable`.